# Grails Illigal Argument Exception

Tags: grails, groovy

```
package com.lk

class Stock {
    static expose = 'stock'
    long id
    String symbol
    String name
    BigDecimal price
    long sharevolume
    long tradevolume
    Float turnover
    BigDecimal change
    BigDecimal changePercentage
    long quantity
    /*Float open*/
    Float hiTrade
    Float loTrade
    Date tradesTransacttime
    Float previousClose

    static mapping = {
            table 'VIEW_CD_TRADE_SUMMARY_NO_DEBT'
            version false
            autoTimestamp false
        }

    static api =
            [
                excludedFields: ["errors", "attached", "properties"],
                list: { params ->
                    if (params.code?.equals('gvt123')) {
                        if (params.exclude) {
                            api.excludedFields = ["errors", "attached", "properties"]
                            params.exclude.split(",").each { api.excludedFields << it?.trim() }
                        } else {
                            api.excludedFields = ["errors", "attached", "properties"]
                        }

                        //println("params -->("+params)

                        params.id ? Stock.findAllByIdInList(params.id.split(",").collect { it as long }) : Stock.list(params)


                    } else {
                        "Invalid Request"
                    }
                        },
                count: { params -> if(params.code?.equals('gvt123')) {
                                          params.id ? Stock.countByIdInList(params.id.split(",").collect { it as long }) : Stock.count()
                                        }else{
                                           0
                                        }}
            ]

}
```

Please Find Above Stock.groovy file and when i run it i got following Exception. Please help me with that.

```
URI /cses/json/stock
Class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message null
```

is there any way handle the Exception the check what entry is comes with fault value. If need i can add Oracle View also.

Stack trace is below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.lk.Stock$__clinit__closure2.doCall(Stock.groovy:41)
        at org.grails.plugins.rest.JsonRestApiController$_closure1.doCall(JsonRestApiController.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-03-26 09:58:54,463 [http-bio-8080-exec-70] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /cses/json/stock
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.lk.Stock$__clinit__closure2.doCall(Stock.groovy:41)
        at org.grails.plugins.rest.JsonRestApiController$_closure1.doCall(JsonRestApiController.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-03-26 09:58:57,676 [http-bio-8080-exec-71] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /cses/json/stock
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.lk.Stock$__clinit__closure2.doCall(Stock.groovy:41)
        at org.grails.plugins.rest.JsonRestApiController$_closure1.doCall(JsonRestApiController.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-03-26 10:08:36,170 [http-bio-8080-exec-83] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /cses/json/stock
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.lk.Stock$__clinit__closure2.doCall(Stock.groovy:41)
        at org.grails.plugins.rest.JsonRestApiController$_closure1.doCall(JsonRestApiController.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-03-26 10:08:42,807 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /cses/json/stock
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.lk.Stock$__clinit__closure2.doCall(Stock.groovy:41)
        at org.grails.plugins.rest.JsonRestApiController$_closure1.doCall(JsonRestApiController.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-03-26 10:09:03,060 [http-bio-8080-exec-29] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /cses/json/stock
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.lk.Stock$__clinit__closure2.doCall(Stock.groovy:41)
        at org.grails.plugins.rest.JsonRestApiController$_closure1.doCall(JsonRestApiController.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-03-26 10:45:28,004 [http-bio-8080-exec-97] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /cses/json/stock
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.lk.Stock$__clinit__closure2.doCall(Stock.groovy:41)
        at org.grails.plugins.rest.JsonRestApiController$_closure1.doCall(JsonRestApiController.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-03-26 10:59:15,551 [http-bio-8080-exec-60] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /cses/json/stock
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.lk.Stock$__clinit__closure2.doCall(Stock.groovy:41)
        at org.grails.plugins.rest.JsonRestApiController$_closure1.doCall(JsonRestApiController.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-03-26 13:18:22,183 [http-bio-8080-exec-62] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /cses/json/stock
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.lk.Stock$__clinit__closure2.doCall(Stock.groovy:41)
        at org.grails.plugins.rest.JsonRestApiController$_closure1.doCall(JsonRestApiController.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadP...
```

**Update** - Add Stack trace.
Thanks.

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: I do not know what "is there any way handle the Exception the check what entry is comes with fault value." means.

If you can create a simple sample app and post that to github along with instructions for how to recreate the problem within the app, that would almost certainly lead to a solution.

Comment: What's on line 41 in Stock.groovy?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the error is in line 41 of your class, which I think is:

```
params.id ? Stock.findAllByIdInList(params.id.split(",").collect { it as long }) : Stock.list(params)
```

Are you sure that `params.id` is a String of longs separated by commas?

And also note that the `collect` method is returning a list of `java.lang.Long`, not the primitive `long` that you want. Why don't you try changing to `java.lang.Long` for the `id` attribute of the `Stock` class? (In fact, I recommend always using the wrapper classes).